# where do i get a driver for a dell 720 for ubuntu 12.04

Tags: printing

I cannot seem to install my dell 720 printer, there seems to be no driver for it and ubuntu does not read the dell driver disc i have

Answer (score 0):

I googled and found this: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HardwareSupportComponentsPrinters/LexmarkPrinters

Specifically: "The Dell photoprinter 720 is just a rebranded Lexmark Z600 printer."

So you can follow the installation instructions for "Lexmark Z600 Series Printers"

I never tried though, and this link seems quite old.

EDIT: for the first step, I believe you should try "sudo apt-get install libstdc++5" instead of what is instructed on the link.

Comment: z600llpddk_2.0-1_i386.deb
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/25416334/Lexmark%20z615%20driver/z600llpddk_2.0-1_i386.deb

z600cups_1.0-1_i386.deb
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/25416334/Lexmark%20z615%20driver/z600cups_1.0-1_i386.deb

Install in the above order, ie, pddk first then the cups file.                                                                       I found these 2 files with the info you gave me and then did the ++5 install from terminal and now I have a printer. THANX!!